# How to sort multiple columns within groups based on a string vector within the group in R?

Tags: r, sorting, vector, dplyr

I am working with election data where in each election the candidates are listed according to a randomly generated alphabet; I am trying to recreate the candidate ordering. So for election 1, the alphabet might be "B, C, A", and thus candidates in that election would appear in order "Bryant, Carlson, Anderson;" candidates in election 2, where the alphabet is "C, A, B," would be listed as "Chavez, Armstrong, Brown;" and so on.

My plan was to split the names into columns with individual letters, and then sort the columns using the alphabet for that election. Here's a minimal df:

```
set.seed(124)

a2000 <- sample(letters[1:9], r = F)
a2001 <- sample(letters[1:9], r = F)
a2002 <- sample(letters[1:9], r = F)


d <- data.frame(
  electionid = rep(1:3, each = 3),
  year = rep(2000:2002, each = 3),
  last1 = sample(letters[1:9], r = T),
  last2 = sample(letters[1:9], r = T),
  alph = I(list(a2000,a2000,a2000,a2001,a2001,a2001,a2002,a2002,a2002)))

last_cols <- c("last1", "last2") # in real dataset, many more columns here

newd <- d %>% 
  group_by(electionid) %>% # order columns within election, not within dataframe
  arrange_at(last_cols, funs(factor(., levels = alph[[1]]))) %>% # set new alphabet for each variable
  mutate(race_order = seq(n())) %>% # create ordering variable
  arrange(electionid) # rearrange for easy checking
```

The key issue is that each alphabet occurs synonymously with the `electionid`, so trying to factor each column (`last1` and `last2`) just using the `alph` variable returns an evaluation error (e.g., `factor level [2] is duplicated.`). When I use options like `alph[[1]]` (in the example), `unique(alph)`, `first(alph)`, `coalesce(alph)`, etc., I get rid of the error, but it seems either to use the first alphabet that occurs in the dataset (`a2000`), or to not sort at all.

What I get with the code above (using dput):

```
structure(list(electionid = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2002L, 2002L), last1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("a", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), 
    last2 = structure(c(1L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("c", 
    "d", "e", "g", "h", "i"), class = "factor"), alph = structure(list(
        c("b", "e", "g", "d", "c", "f", "h", "a", "i"), c("b", 
        "e", "g", "d", "c", "f", "h", "a", "i"), c("b", "e", 
        "g", "d", "c", "f", "h", "a", "i"), c("a", "h", "g", 
        "d", "b", "e", "f", "i", "c"), c("a", "h", "g", "d", 
        "b", "e", "f", "i", "c"), c("a", "h", "g", "d", "b", 
        "e", "f", "i", "c"), c("a", "g", "h", "e", "d", "b", 
        "f", "i", "c"), c("a", "g", "h", "e", "d", "b", "f", 
        "i", "c"), c("a", "g", "h", "e", "d", "b", "f", "i", 
        "c")), class = "AsIs"), race_order = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), vars = "electionid", indices = list(
    0:2, 3:5, 6:8), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 3L, labels = structure(list(
    electionid = 1:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), vars = "electionid", indices = list(0:2, 3:5, 6:8), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 3L))
```

Which prints as:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   electionid [3]
  electionid  year last1 last2 alph      race_order
       <int> <int> <fct> <fct> <I(list)>      <int>
1          1  2000 c     b     <chr [9]>          1 # This is with alphabet a2000
2          1  2000 h     i     <chr [9]>          2 # This is with alphabet a2000
3          1  2000 d     b     <chr [9]>          3 # This is with alphabet a2000
4          2  2001 h     c     <chr [9]>          1 # This is with alphabet a2001
5          2  2001 c     b     <chr [9]>          2 # This is with alphabet a2001
6          2  2001 d     h     <chr [9]>          3 # This is with alphabet a2001
7          3  2002 h     g     <chr [9]>          1 # This is with alphabet a2002
8          3  2002 a     c     <chr [9]>          2 # This is with alphabet a2002
9          3  2002 i     d     <chr [9]>          3 # This is with alphabet a2002
```

What I'd like to get:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 6
# Groups:   electionid [3]
  electionid  year last1 last2 alph      race_order
       <int> <int> <fct> <fct> <I(list)>      <int>
1          1  2000 d     b     <chr [9]>          1 # Previously ranked 3
2          1  2000 h     i     <chr [9]>          2
3          1  2000 c     b     <chr [9]>          3 # Previously ranked 1
4          2  2001 c     b     <chr [9]>          1 # Previously ranked 2
5          2  2001 h     c     <chr [9]>          2 # Previously ranked 1
6          2  2001 d     h     <chr [9]>          3
7          3  2002 h     g     <chr [9]>          1 
8          3  2002 a     c     <chr [9]>          2
9          3  2002 i     d     <chr [9]>          3
```

In other words, I would generate a count variable (`race_order`) that recreates where each candidate would be listed based on applying that election's unique alphabet to their name!

Comment: Thank you for creating a reproducible example, however, this is pretty hard to follow and its difficult to understand what you are asking. Can you maybe just show two data.frame's of what you are starting with and where you are trying to go? Perhaps some details around why the ordering is the way it is for 1 or 2 rows of the output.

Comment: Let me know if these edits help clarify! Thank you for your comment.